# DataService fails on certain parameter combinations

Tags: entity-framework, ado.net-entity-data-model, wcf-data-services

I am using ADO.NET DataService Query for my application. I noticed that for some query parameter-combinations causes the DataServiceQuery to throw an exception. However, it does not throw any error if I add extra dummy parameters (e.g. `JNO != null`).

```
string bNo = "00000001";
DateTime targetTime = DateTime.Today;
```

Here are the combinations that  I tried:

1. No Error

   this.proxy.T_BRecord
       .Where(b =>
           b.RecordDate == targetTime)
2. No Error

   this.proxy.T_BRecord
       .Where(b =>
           b.JNO == bNo)
3. Error Thrown - Bad Request

   this.proxy.T_BathRecord
       .Where(b =>
           b.JNO == bNo &&
           b.RecordDate == targetTime)
4. No Error

   this.proxy.T_BRecord
       .Where(b =>
           b.RecordDate == targetTime &&
           b.JNO == bNo &&
           b.JNO != null)

I am trying to search a way to debug the data service. I already tried to add the verbose debug settings as suggested [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/phaniraj/archive/2008/06/18/debugging-ado-net-data-services.aspx). But the error is just a raw Bad Request HTML tag with no error details. The code did not reach the request of data via URI. I am suspecting it might be an entity framework DLL problem but I cannot find any documentation on the problem.

When I typed the query URI manually via the browser it does return a query result. I used the following query URI:

```
http://localhost:9009/BabyDBSvc.svc/T_BRecord()?$filter=(RecordDate%20ge%20datetime'2013-01-04T00%3A00%3A00')%20and%20(JNO%20eq%20'0000000004')
```

And I got the following XML result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="shift_jis" standalone="yes"?>
<feed xml:base="http://localhost:9009/BabyDBSvc.svc/" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <title type="text">T_BathRecord</title>
  <id>http://localhost:9009/BabyDBSvc.svc/T_BRecord</id>
  <updated>2013-01-04T06:06:49Z</updated>
  <author>
    <name />
  </author>
  <link rel="self" title="T_BathRecord" href="T_BRecord" />
</feed>
```

Comment: Hi @Nap, did you ever solve this one?  Only thing I can think of the request is being cached, and adding an extra parameter on query string makes it not cached.

Comment: Also, double check the encoding for the date param.

Comment: @Carl Prothman I already forgot about this bug. I think it might be caused by a cache as you stated. Since there is no clear fix to this, I would delete this question in a week if there is no more new info.